# MSVC Assembly function arguments C++ vs _asm

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

I have a function which takes 3 arguments, dest, src0, src1, each a pointer to data of size 12. I made two versions. One is written in C and optimized by the compiler, the other one is fully written in _asm. So yeah. 3 arguments? I naturally do something like:

```
mov ecx, [src0]
mov edx, [src1]
mov eax, [dest]
```

I am a bit confused by the compiler, as it saw fit to add the following:

```
_src0$ = -8                     ; size = 4
_dest$ = -4                     ; size = 4
_src1$ = 8                      ; size = 4
?vm_vec_add_scalar_asm@@YAXPAUvec3d@@PBU1@1@Z PROC  ; vm_vec_add_scalar_asm
; _dest$ = ecx
; _src0$ = edx

; 20   : {

sub esp, 8
mov DWORD PTR _src0$[esp+8], edx
mov DWORD PTR _dest$[esp+8], ecx

; 21   :    _asm
; 22   :    {
; 23   :        mov ecx, [src0]

mov ecx, DWORD PTR _src0$[esp+8]

; 24   :            mov edx, [src1]

mov edx, DWORD PTR _src1$[esp+4]

; 25   :            mov eax, [dest]

mov eax, DWORD PTR _dest$[esp+8]

Function body etc.

add esp, 8
ret 0
```

What does the _src0$[esp+8] etc. even means? Why does it do all this stuff before my code? Why does it try to [apparently]stack anything so badly?

In comparison, the C++ version has only the following before its body, which is pretty similar:

```
_src1$ = 8                      ; size = 4
?vm_vec_add@@YAXPAUvec3d@@PBU1@1@Z PROC         ; vm_vec_add
; _dest$ = ecx
; _src0$ = edx

mov eax, DWORD PTR _src1$[esp-4]
```

Why is this little sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of Mats Petersson explained `__fastcall`. But I guess that is not exactly what you're asking ...

Actually `_src0$[esp+8]` just means `[_src0$ + esp + 8]`, and `_src0$` is defined above:

```
_src0$ = -8                     ; size = 4
```

So, the whole expression `_src0$[esp+8]` is nothing but `[esp]` ...

To see why it does all these stuff, you should probably first understand what Mats Petersson said in his post, the `__fastcall`, or more generally, what is a **calling convention**. See the link in his post for detailed informations.

Assuming that you have understood `__fastcall`, now let's see what happens to your codes. The compiler is using `__fastcall`. Your callee function is `f(dst, src0, src1)`, which requires `3` parameters, so according to the calling convention, when a caller calls `f`, it does the following:

1. Move `dst` to `ecx` and `src0` to `edx`
2. Push `src1` onto the stack
3. Push the 4 bytes return address onto the stack
4. Go to the starting address of the function `f`

And the callee `f`, when its code begins, then knows where the parameters are: `dst` and `src0` are in the registers `ecx` and `edx`, respectively; `esp` is pointing to the 4 bytes return address, but the 4 bytes below it (i.e. DWORD PTR[esp+4]) is exactly `src1`.

So, in your "C++ version", the function `f` just does what it should do:

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR _src1$[esp-4]
```

Here `_src1$ = 8`, so `_src1$[esp-4]` is exactly `[esp+4]`. See, it just retrieves the parameter `src1` and stores it in `eax`.

There is however a tricky point here. In the code of `f`, if you want to use the parameter `src1` multiple times, you can certainly do that, because it's always stored in the stack, right below the return address; but what if you want to use `dst` and `src0` multiple times? They are in the registers, and can be destroyed at any time.

So in that case, the compiler should do the following: right after entering the function `f`, it should remember the current values of `ecx` and `edx` (by pushing them onto the stack). These 8 bytes are the so-called "shadow space". It is not done in your "C++ version", probably because the compiler knows for sure that these two parameters will not be used multiple times, or that it can handle it properly some other way.

Now, what happens to your `_asm` version? The problem here is that you are using inline assembly. The compiler then loses its control to the registers, and it cannot assume that the registers `ecx` and `edx` are safe in your `_asm` block (they are actually not, since you used them in the `_asm` block). Thus it is forced to save them at the beginning of the function.

The saving goes as follows: it first raises `esp` by 8 bytes (`sub esp, 8`), then move `edx` and `ecx` to `[esp]` and `[esp+4]` respectively.

And then it can enter safely your `_asm` block. Now in its mind (if it has one), the picture is that `[esp]` is `src0`, `[esp+4]` is `dst`, `[esp+8]` is the 4 byte return address, and `[esp+12]` is `src1`. It no longer thinks about `ecx` and `edx`.

Thus your first instruction in the `_asm` block, `mov ecx, [src0]`, should be interpreted as `mov ecx, [esp]`, which is the same as

```
mov ecx, DWORD PTR _src0$[esp+8]
```

and the same for the other two instructions.

At this point, you might say, aha it's doing stupid things, I don't want it to waste time and space on that, is there a way?

Well there is a way - do not use inline assembly... it's convenient, but there is a compromise.

You can write the assembly function `f` in a `.asm` source file and `public` it. In the `C/C++` code, declare it as `extern 'C' f(...)`. Then, when you begin your assembly function `f`, you can play directly with your `ecx` and `edx`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has decided to use a  calling convention that uses "pass arguments in registers" aka `__fastcall`. This allows the compiler to pass some of the arguments in registers, instead of pushing onto stack, and this can reduce the overhead in the call, because moving from a variable to a register is faster than pushing onto the stack, and it's now already in a register when we get to the callee function, so no need to read it from the stack.

There is a lot more information about how calling conventions work on the web. The wikipedia article on [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) is a good starting point.